# Adding an envelope attachment through REST

Tags: docusignapi

At the bottom of [this page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents) a feature allowing developers to attach documents which don't get converted to PDF is described, but I've been unable to find documentation on how to actually do it. I'm trying to attach an excel spreadsheet and have it remain an excel spreadsheet when the envelope goes out to my signers.

I'm using this to attach the spreadsheet:

```
excel_add_resp = requests.put('https://' + api_url + '/restapi/v2/accounts/' + acnt_id + '/envelopes/' + env_id + '/documents',
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data = json.dumps(
    {
        'documents': [
        {
            'documentId': '2',
            'name': xl_file.split('/')[-1],
            'fileExtension': 'xlsx',
            'documentBase64': xlwb_b64
        }
      ]
    }
  )
)
```

But it gets converted to a 500+ page pdf. Is there a parameter I can add to my payload to keep it as a spreadsheet or am I hitting the wrong endpoint entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong endpoint if you want to add any document as an EnvelopeAttachment, the correct endpoint is below and more details are available [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeAttachments/create)

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/attachments
```

The endpoint which you are using is adding documents in an envelope so that those are available on Signing screen, whereas EnvelopeAttachments are the document which will be available only through API.

Comment: Thank you Amit - can you clarify whether it's possible to have a document which is not a pdf accessible/downloadable (but not signable) by a user who is supposed to sign a document? When I add the sheet as an attachment (replacing 'documentId' with 'attachmentId', removing 'fileExtension' and replacing 'documentBase64' with 'data' in my json payload) I get a http 200 but I no longer see the attachment in the drafts view.

Comment: Yes, you cannot see Attachments in the Envelope in the draft or sent or signing view. Envelope API Attachments are normally used when you want to add something in the Envelope as metadata but should not be visible to any recipient on the Envelope. Whereas what I understood from your last comment is you want  to Shown XLS as XLS to the recipient on the Signing screen, but that is not possible because once you add any Document in Envelope for Signing then DocuSign converts everything into PDF format.

Comment: There are few XLS Print properties which you can set in XLS so that when DocuSign converts this XLS to PDF then it should maintain those properties which can render XLS as nice readable format. DocuSign uses same logic which you can try by Printing XLS as PDF in your local machine, and see how it looks by applying diff printing settings.

Comment: If I were to add myself as the first signer and append the spreadsheet as a signer attachment instead, would that then be downloadable by later signers as a spreadsheet?

Comment: No, if you will manually upload it as an Attachment then also DocuSign will convert it as PDF and another Signer will not be able to see it as an XLS file.